# ajax call to the wrong link path

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have page with two different action call,this is the first call which is working OK :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("edit", "user", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    ...
}
```

At the end of page I put this call to different action :

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "user/validate",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                hiddenField1: hidden,
                hiddenField2: "hiddenValue2",
            },
            success: function () {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
```

when I debug the Ajax call when I click on button I check in the console that the URL 
which I trying to run is **http.../user/Edit/user/validate** instead of **http../user/validate** how should I avoid it?

The ajax call is not inside using of the first call,I put it at the end of the page...

Comment: try this `url: '@Url.Action("validate", "user")',`

Comment: try `url : "@Url.Action('validate')`

Comment: try with this: `url: "/validate",`

Comment: @MohitArora- try it and I got the same error its concatenate the action like  /user/Edit/@Url.Action("validate", "user")'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this `url: "user/validate",`

to this `url: "../../user/validate",`

or I think you can simply use: `url: "../validate",`

Comment: Thanks ,this is the answer!,can you please explain why ?voted up

Comment: because jQuery sets the urls according to the file it is included to, so the file that you're using this jQuery code in is I suppose in this folder "user/Edit/" so it needs to go back two directories and then go to your desired url.